# Swagger hub return 504 when api is tried

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swaggerhub

The application I am documenting is accessible on a VPN, I defined the api on swagger-hub, and added the server url. But when I try to execute it, swagger-hub returns 504, My understanding is because the url is not accessible on internet, swagger-hub is not able hit it even though my system is connected to vpn. Is it correct? How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the "Try it out" functionality of the Swagger UI within SwaggerHub, then this would be expected.

"Try it out" requests are not sent from your browser, instead they are sent from our systems. You will need to configure your firewall/vpn to allow connections from SwaggerHub. You can find more information in the link here:
https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/ip-addresses.html